# Measure performance for small application

Tags: python, performance, rust, monitoring, benchmarking

I wrote a statusbar for Sway WM (https://swaywm.org), basically print every second some information (loadavg, cpu usage, memory usage, time, ...).

The project (https://gitlab.com/Yellowhat/statusbar) is purely to learn about CI/CD and how to measure performance (if possible in a noisy environment).

Initially the project was all written in `python` but some time ago I decided to write a functionally equivalent in `rust` (https://gitlab.com/Yellowhat/statusbar/-/tree/master/tools/rust) (they print out exactly the same information).

Looking at the number of instructions run (`I refs` using `cachegrind`, slimmed version) per second of execution:

- `python`: ~800k
- `rust`: ~35k

I could conclude that the `rust` version is much "lighter" than the `python` one.

As the statusbar will run continuosly while the system is running, I want to understand the impact that it has on my system. So I decided to monitor my system using the following `python` script while idling (do not touch the computer for 1 hour, 100% brightness):

```py
from time import sleep

while True:
    stat = open("/proc/stat").readlines()[0].split()[1:8]
    power = float(open("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now").read().strip()) / 10**6
    print(f"{stat},{power}")
    sleep(1)
```

- `/proc/stat` returns how much CPU time (jiffies) is spent in:

  - `user`: normal processes executing in user mode
  - `nice`: niced processes executing in user mode
  - `system`: processes executing in kernel mode
  - `idle`: twiddling thumbs
  - `iowait`: waiting for I/O to complete
  - `irq`: servicing interrupts
  - `softirq`: servicing softirqs
- `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now` returns how much power (micro Watt) is taken from the battery

I have compared 4 cases:

1. **tty**: boot the computer and run the script from `tty`
2. **sway**: boot the computer, start `sway` (without a bar), open the terminal and run the script
3. **sway barpy**: boot the computer, start `sway` (with the `python` version), open the terminal and run the script
4. **sway barrs**: boot the computer, start `sway` (with the `rust` version), open the terminal and run the script

The following graph shows the `SUM(user_t, nice_t, system_t, iowait_t, irq_t, softirq_t) - SUM(user_t0, nice_t0, system_t0, iowait_t0, irq_t0, softirq_t0)`, (how much time was spent by all CPUs not idling) - (the initial value at the beginning of the test), versus time for the 4 cases:

[image: CPU Time]

As you can see, **tty** is the lowest, followed by **sway**, but interestingly the `rust` version is much higher than the `python` one.

The following graph shows the power versus time for the 4 cases:

[image: Power]

As you can see, **tty** has the lowest consumption, followed by **sway**, very close by `rust` and `python` at last. This is the kind of result I would expect.

The first graph would suggest that, in this instance, `rust` is not lighter than `python`.

Are there more reliable way to measure "light" applications?
Am I misunderstanding the `/proc/stat` content?

Thanks

## Update 1

The following graph shows the `user_t - user_t0`, `nice_t - nice_t0`, `system_t - system_t0` versus time for `python` and `rust`:

[image: User, Nice, System]

`user` are similar instead `system` and `nice` are much higher for `rust`.

## Update 2

As suggested by Peter Cordes I have run:

```
perf stat -a -d -e cpu-cycles,cycles,cycles:u,instructions,instructions:u -r 10 <binary>
```

The following tables summarise the results:

| Version | Duration | cpu-cycles | cycles | cycles:u | instructions | instructions:u |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| python | 0 | 285,248,768 | 285,492,709 | 215,681,759 | 323,852,866 | 278,792,657 |
| python | 60 | 3,038,749,610 | 3,046,770,477 | 1,360,477,472 | 2,425,399,588 | 1,612,134,730 |
| python | 120 | 5,802,965,874 | 5,818,929,489 | 2,496,192,062 | 4,536,305,443 | 2,890,941,664 |
| rust | 0 | 1,165,223 | 1,165,869 | 304,188 | 1,319,168 | 442,565 |
| rust | 60 | 3,791,712,516 | 3,799,515,523 | 1,654,232,537 | 3,355,917,423 | 2,073,096,815 |
| rust | 120 | 7,878,549,570 | 7,897,534,278 | 3,341,698,282 | 6,665,643,064 | 4,144,148,632 |

Removing the initial value (duration = 0) and dividing by the duration:

| Version | Duration | cpu-cycles | cycles | cycles:u | instructions | instructions:u |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| python | 60 | 45,891,681 | 46,021,296 | 19,079,929 | 35,025,779 | 22,222,368 |
| python | 120 | 45,980,976 | 46,111,973 | 19,004,253 | 35,103,771 | 21,767,908 |
| rust | 60 | 63,175,788 | 63,305,828 | 27,565,472 | 55,909,971 | 34,544,238 |
| rust | 120 | 65,644,870 | 65,803,070 | 27,844,951 | 55,536,032 | 34,530,884 |

Again, seems that `rust` version is running more cycles/instructions than the `python` one.

## Update 3

```sh
$ valgrind \
    --tool=cachegrind \
    --cachegrind-out-file=/dev/null \
    --trace-children=yes \
    --I1=32768,8,64 \
    --D1=32768,8,64 \
    --LL=8388608,16,64 \
    --cache-sim=yes \
    --branch-sim=yes \
    <binary>
```

Run for 120 seconds:

- `python` version:

```sh
I   refs:      328,117,776
I1  misses:      5,268,249
LLi misses:         15,274
I1  miss rate:        1.61%
LLi miss rate:        0.00%

D   refs:      135,851,173  (95,116,936 rd   + 40,734,237 wr)
D1  misses:      4,717,331  ( 4,145,263 rd   +    572,068 wr)
LLd misses:        167,298  (    57,266 rd   +    110,032 wr)
D1  miss rate:         3.5% (       4.4%     +        1.4%  )
LLd miss rate:         0.1% (       0.1%     +        0.3%  )

LL refs:         9,985,580  ( 9,413,512 rd   +    572,068 wr)
LL misses:         182,572  (    72,540 rd   +    110,032 wr)
LL miss rate:          0.0% (       0.0%     +        0.3%  )

Branches:       60,115,083  (56,103,351 cond +  4,011,732 ind)
Mispredicts:     5,661,255  ( 4,245,148 cond +  1,416,107 ind)
Mispred rate:          9.4% (       7.6%     +       35.3%   )
```

- `rust` version:

```sh
I   refs:      100,950,027
I1  misses:        351,835
LLi misses:          5,859
I1  miss rate:        0.35%
LLi miss rate:        0.01%

D   refs:       44,227,512  (24,903,985 rd   + 19,323,527 wr)
D1  misses:        670,307  (   341,521 rd   +    328,786 wr)
LLd misses:         34,962  (    20,657 rd   +     14,305 wr)
D1  miss rate:         1.5% (       1.4%     +        1.7%  )
LLd miss rate:         0.1% (       0.1%     +        0.1%  )

LL refs:         1,022,142  (   693,356 rd   +    328,786 wr)
LL misses:          40,821  (    26,516 rd   +     14,305 wr)
LL miss rate:          0.0% (       0.0%     +        0.1%  )

Branches:       19,868,173  (18,608,630 cond +  1,259,543 ind)
Mispredicts:     1,289,209  (   771,555 cond +    517,654 ind)
Mispred rate:          6.5% (       4.1%     +       41.1%   )
```

Comment: Physics terminology: that energy is measured in Joules, power in  Watts.  An instantaneous measurement of the (micro) Watts right now is power, not energy.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo, now correct

Comment: Maybe you could plot separately `user`, `nice`, `system` etc to at least know where to start digging?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: Start digging for what?  CPython is known to be a slow interpreter; it's not totally surprising that a Python program run under it uses significantly more energy (and cycles).  Maybe that level of difference is surprising if it's only waking up every second to read some kernel files, if that's what you meant?  So possibly the Python program is waking up more; worth checking with `strace` on how often / how long it's sleeping.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the author wants to understand why could Rust spend twice as more CPU time than the Python's version

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, thanks for the suggestion I have updated the question. Yes I would like to understand why `rust` spends much more CPU time than `python`.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov: Oh, yes, that was super buried in the middle of the question, and the graph labels are pretty small to be readable (on my 1920x1200 screen).  After looking at the energy graph and instruction-count numbers, I assumed the Rust process was going to be using less CPU time.  Maybe *it's* not sleeping properly, and making the kernel run more kernel-instructions to format text files on the fly as it reads them.  (And to gather the data it's going to output.)  But no, that would make it use more energy.

Comment: @PeterCordes to be honest the fact that `rust` spends more CPU time doing `system` leads me to think that the kernel is doing more but why the energy consumption is lower? Is there a way to measure the entire thing?

Comment: `perf stat` for `instructions` and/or `cycles` instead of their `instruction:u` user-space-only versions might tell you something.  (You may need to adjust `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid`, I find `0` is a good setting for my desktop.)  With CPU frequency being dynamic, having the CPU stay at a lower frequency would mean more time running this, but probably fewer core clock cycles, due to reduced cache-miss penalty.  (And maybe lower total energy for the same work).  So looking at instructions is the best way to see if it's the same amount of "work".

Comment: Depending on how you run the `barpy` or `barrs` programs they will have an effect only on "nice" or only on "user", but not both.

Comment: As suggesteed by @PeterCordes I have gathered some metrics using `perf stat`

Comment: I looked again at your first graph.  It does show `barrs` using more CPU time, as well as cycles and instructions, so it's not a clock-speed different.  I think I didn't look carefully enough earlier, and didn't notice until now that your suggestion of the Rust version being "lighter weird" was inconsistent with that.  It might have many fewer I-cache misses (which makes some sense for compiled Rust vs. interpreted Python), but maybe isn't sleeping properly or as long as you intended so uses more cycles.  Is "I refs" supposed to count instructions, or I-cache misses?

Comment: `I refs` is counting instruction reads.

Comment: I have updated (3) the post with the `cachegrind` results running on my laptop. The number of instructions (`I refs`), cache read/write (`D refs`) and branches is 3 times lower for `rust`. The number of cache level 1 cache (`L1`) is much much lower. May this explain why `rust` is less power hungry?